# Get index value when using ForEach - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

**Problem**

I am displaying a list of data, using a `ForEach` statement, when the user interacts with each view the size changes and displays in fullscreen, the problem is the state changes the size of each view and not just of the one selected. Trying to replicate the App Store home page cards.

**What I am trying**

I thought maybe using the index value I could

```
 ForEach(objects.indices, id: \.self) { index in
          ObjectView(home: self.objects[index], showContent: self.$showContent)
 }
```

And then maybe store the index value, then only change the size if the object index matches the stored index value. However when trying to use indices I get the following error.

> Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'indices'

**Full Code:**

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var show = false // Maybe set this to true when tapped then use self.objects[index].show for Fram size, but not sure how to get index or make this work
}

struct AppView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @Binding var showContent: Bool


        var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            VStack() {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 32) {
                    ForEach(objectData, id: \.id) { item in
                        GeometryReader { geometry in

                            ContentView(object: item, showContent: self.$showContent)

                            .offset(y: self.showContent ? -geometry.frame(in: .global).minY : 0)

                        }
                        .frame(height: self.showContent ? screen.height : 464)
                        .frame(maxWidth: self.showContent ? .infinity : screen.width - 40)
                    }
                }.offset(x: 0, y: -80)

            }.padding(.bottom, 300)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0))

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
}


struct ObjectCardView: View {

var object: Object
@Binding var showContent:Bool


    var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

                    Image(object.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(height: self.showContent ? 364 : 284)
                        .clipped()       
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.session.selectedObject = self.object
                            self.showContent.toggle()
                        }

                        if showContent {
                         VStack {
                              DetailsView(object: Object)
                          }
                        }


          }

     }
 }
```

PS: I have an unrelated view issue here which is the child scroll view changes the parent scroll view, and tapping on the child actually interacts with the content in the parent. So if I open a card and scroll then tap, the AppView scroll view also scrolls and will open/close other cards.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [String](repeating: "row", count: 10)
```

.....

```
ForEach(arr.indices) { i in
    Text(self.arr[i] + "\(i)")
}
```

Why?? `var indices: Range<Int> { get }` is type of `Range<Int>`